# Non escaped non ASCII character in non ASCII-8BIT script

Tags: ruby, regex, utf-8, brakeman

I have this regex:

```
/\「(?>[^\「\」\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*\」/
```

(with `# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-` in my file), which runs without any errors in my application. When I use the `brakeman` gem to check my application, it returns the following:

```
WARNING: invalid multibyte character: /\「(?>[^\「\」\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*\」/ for "\\「(?>[^\\「\\」\\\\]+|\\\\{2}|\\\\.)*\\」" ""

+Errors+
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>>
| Error                                                                                                     >>
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>
| /.../n has a non escaped non ASCII character in non ASCII-8BIT script: /\「(?>[^\「\」\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*\」/>>
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->>
```

1) Why is the warning displayed? (Isn't the bracket character escaped?)
2) Will anything bad happen if I ignore the warning?
3) Is there anyway to change my code so that it achieves the same objective but does not have this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know anything about `brakeman`. But as your file is encoded in UTF-8, the byte stream of your regular expression is read in ASCII/ANSI with code page Windows-1252

```
/\ã€Œ(?>[^\ã€Œ\ã€\\]+|\\{2}|\\. )*\ã€/
```

which is with hexadecimal values

```
2F 5C E3 80 8C 28 3F 3E 5B 5E 5C E3 80 8C 5C E3 80 8D 5C 5C 5D 2B 7C 5C 5C 7B 32 7D 7C 5C 5C 2E 29 2A 5C E3 80 8D 2F
```

As you can see there are many "characters" (bytes) with a code value greater 127 decimal (hexadecimal 7F) without a backslash before if the byte stream is not first converted from UTF-8 to Unicode (usually UTF-16 Little Endian).

It is possible to write Perl regular expressions always without any character with a code value greater 127 even if the expression should find characters in full Unicode range.

In the scripts forum of text editor UltraEdit there is the topic [Creating a Perl regular expression string with ANSI/Unicode characters](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=14216) which explains how such expression can be created and contains additionally a link to an UltraEdit script which uses mainly JavaScript code to convert a regular expression with ANSI or Unicode characters inside to an expression using their hexadecimal representations and therefore only ASCII characters.

Using this UltraEdit script within UltraEdit on your regular expression after removing the not necessary backslahes before the Unicode characters puts into clipboard the Perl regular expression string

```
/\x{300c}(?>[^\x{300c}\x{300d}\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*\x{300d}/
```

For a Ruby script `\u` must be used instead of `\x` resulting in the expression:

```
/\u{300c}(?>[^\u{300c}\u{300d}\\]+|\\{2}|\\.)*\u{300d}/
```

And this regular expression string should find the same as your string without producing any warning by `brakeman` as it consists now only of ASCII characters with a code value smaller than 128 decimal.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, the syntax for ruby is `\u{}` instead of `\x{}` so it would be helpful if you updated your answer to include that note.